# Decrypt encfs with SJCL

Tags: javascript, xml, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying for few days to do the thing below:

I have on my hard drive/server files which were encrypted with ENCFS (aes256). What i want to do is to decrypt them on my browser (client side) with a JavaScript library.
For now, I've found two js library :

- CryptoJS: I've give up this one because the decryption is really really long;
- SJCL: this one is really nice and after some bench of encryption/decryption, it appears this one is 100x faster than CryptoJS.

So, okay. I'm trying to work with SJCL since few days... I've good results for encrypt and decrypt file with the library but I've some troubles with decryption of files encrypted with encfs.

I'm doing steps in this order:

- Read xml meta information file and get information for SJCL. Here is SJCL need and the corresponding element I'd choose in the xml file:

```
iv : chainedNameIV
v : 1 (default value)
iter : kdfIterations
ks : keySize
ts : blockSize
mode : 'ccm'
adata : '' (empty value...)
cipher : aes
salt : saltData
ct : ct is the content of the file i want to decrypt.
```

I think I have a problem in the « selection » of elements I'm setting for my chain... Here is what I proceed with js code.

Functions file which can get information from xml file and decrypt the file.

```
var decrypt = {

    getMetaInfos: function(file) {
        var ks   = file.getElementsByTagName('keySize');
        var iv   = file.getElementsByTagName('chainedNameIV');
        var salt = file.getElementsByTagName('saltData');
        var iter = file.getElementsByTagName('kdfIterations');
        var ts   = file.getElementsByTagName('blockSize');

        var infos = {};

        infos.iv     = iv[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        infos.v      = 1;
        infos.iter   = iter[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        infos.ks     = ks[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        infos.ts     = ts[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        infos.mode   = 'ccm';
        infos.adata  = '';
        infos.cipher = 'aes';
        infos.salt   = salt[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        infos.ct     = '';

        return infos;
    },

    getFileContent: function(file) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('POST', 'ajax.php', false);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send('t=getFile&file='+file);

        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
            return request.responseText;
        }       
    },

    decryptFile: function(fileContent, metaInfos, passphrase) {
        metaInfos.ct = fileContent;
        console.log(metaInfos);
        console.log(sjcl.decrypt(passphrase, metaInfos));
    },

    createFile: function(file) {
        return;
    }

}
```

If you look at the `decryptFile` function, there are two `console.log`. The first one is showing my object with all meta information and the content of the file i want to decrypt and the second is the one which displays the js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

And here is my controller file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Declare some vars
    var xmlFile = 'files/coffre/ecfs6.xml';
    var passPhrase = 'passphrase';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Ajax request
    request.onload = function() {
        xmlData = new DOMParser().parseFromString(request.responseText, 'text/xml');

        // Get meta informations which'll help to decrypt files in folder (encfs config)
        xmlData = decrypt.getMetaInfos(xmlData);

        // Add eventlistener on link click to do all the stuff we need
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var _i = 0; _i < links.length; _i++) {
            links[_i].onclick = function linkClicked() {

                var fileUrl = this.href;
                var fileContent = decrypt.getFileContent(fileUrl);  

                var decryptedFile = decrypt.decryptFile(fileContent, xmlData, passPhrase);  

                return false;
            };
        }
    }

    // Sending request 
    request.open('GET', xmlFile, false);
    request.send();
}
```

I'm working with AJAX and a PHP script to get the content of the file (`file_get_contents`) and I encode my data with `utf8_encode` before returning them to my js script. All the data I store seems to be ok.

To finish, this is my xml file generated when I encrypt my folder with `encfs` (working on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="10">
<cfg class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="20">
    <version>20100713</version>
    <creator>EncFS 1.7.4</creator>
    <cipherAlg class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <name>ssl/aes</name>
        <major>3</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </cipherAlg>
    <nameAlg>
        <name>nameio/null</name>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </nameAlg>
    <keySize>256</keySize>
    <blockSize>1024</blockSize>
    <uniqueIV>0</uniqueIV>
    <chainedNameIV>1</chainedNameIV>
    <externalIVChaining>0</externalIVChaining>
    <blockMACBytes>0</blockMACBytes>
    <blockMACRandBytes>0</blockMACRandBytes>
    <allowHoles>1</allowHoles>
    <encodedKeySize>52</encodedKeySize>
    <encodedKeyData>
9cyR/qRvdP4mq9pPOOhwPJSrQ4qzmABRRX3JtzLdhSfMkryDxzH+w+OKM7Oa9PFvIUWNiQ==
    </encodedKeyData>
    <saltLen>20</saltLen>
    <saltData>
rPeAGiV5hXourhX4WAu6tENiBeE=
    </saltData>
    <kdfIterations>180192</kdfIterations>
    <desiredKDFDuration>500</desiredKDFDuration>
</cfg>
</boost_serialization>
```

My questions are next: Am I getting the goods xml fields? Did I missed something ? I hope someone can help me. Don't be afraid to ask me more questions, I'll enjoy to answer them.

Comment: Very long question for a syntax error. Are you sure that `var decrypt = {` is correct?

Comment: A dumb question - is sjcl included at all? If you are sure that `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error comes from `console.log(sjcl.decrypt(passphrase, metaInfos));` then it means that either `sjcl` is not defined or `sjcl.decrypt` not defined.